# From webapp2 to Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to find an equivalent to:

`self.request.get_all("value")` (from webapp2)

on flask, the fact is i'm very new to flask and web development. I cant find anything similar on flasks documentation

Comment: im working with google app engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all values for a particular key in the request, use `getlist`:

```
request.args.getlist('value')
```

`request.args` returns a `MultiDict` object, as documented [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist)